# Help with this Advanced Definite Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I've been working on this problem for too long so I've decided to come and ask for some help.

Can someone help me work out the following? If you can show the steps, that would be super helpful because I apparently have no idea how to approach this problem.

$b_{i}, c,$ and $d$ are constants
$$
b(x) = b_{i} - c + \sqrt{c^2-x^2} + d - \sqrt{d^2-x^2}
$$
$$
I=\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{1}{b(x)^3}dx
$$
Thanks!

Comment: The integrand is an even function, if that somehow helps. Also, you let $b\equiv b_i-c+d$ for simplicity.

Comment: @Lovsovs Note that the $c$ and $d$ are also the same constants under the root sign, I dont know if this is an important point in finding a solution.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Do you mean that $c=d$? How do you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @Lovsovs No, I mean $c$ is both inside and outside the root sign, dont know why. The integral doesnt seem susceptible to any standard method.

Comment: If $b=0$ (as I defined it above), the integral evaluates to the ugly $1/((c^2 - 
  d^2)^3))(a (-2 a^2 (\sqrt{-a^2 + c^2} + \sqrt{-a^2 + d^2}) + 
     d^2 (3 \sqrt{-a^2 + c^2} + 2 \sqrt{-a^2 + d^2}) + 
     c^2 (2 \sqrt{-a^2 + c^2} + 3 \sqrt{-a^2 + d^2})) + 
  3 c^2 d^2 (\arctan[a/\sqrt{-a^2 + c^2}] + \arctan[a/\sqrt{-a^2 + d^2}])$

Comment: @Lovsovs How did you get that ? (Dont say you put it in wolfram).

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Almost, I put it in Mathematica. ;P

Comment: @Lovsovs Well, it looks like something one ought to be able to derive for oneself. What if $b\neq 0$ ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Then Mathematica chokes.

Comment: @Lovsovs I have just convinced  myself that if $b=0$ and one sets $y=\sqrt{\frac{c^2-x^2}{d^2-x^2}}$ one gets the intergral of a rational expression of $y$ times $\sqrt{c^2-d^2y^2}$ which as is well known can be integrated.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus That is unfortunately beyond my capabilities :)

Comment: @Lovsovs Not sure what you mean. What is beyond you ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Being able to carry out that integration by hand.

Comment: @Lovsovs Yeah but in theory it's possible